# how to check if textfield (keyboardType: TextInputType.number) contains number less than 50?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a simple TextField to get a number and checking if it contains a number less than 50.
Note : keyboardType: TextInputType.number

Here is my how im doing it:

```
Column(
  children: [
    TextField(
      controller: textEditingController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: 'Number of Questions',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17),
      ),
    ),
    InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        if (textEditingController.text == '50') {
          print(textEditingController.text);
        } else {
          showInSnackBar();
        }
      },
      child: Text(
        'Start',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 26,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          letterSpacing: 2,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    textEditingController.addListener(_handleNumber);
  }

  void _handleNumber(){
      if(textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty){
        var num = int.parse(textEditingController.text);
        if(num <= 50){....}
      }
  }
```

Comment: This is working fine but giving this error in terminal when no number in TextField : The following FormatException was thrown while dispatching notifications for TextEditingController: Invalid number (at character 1) ^

Comment: I made an adjustment - you just have to check if the text is empty or not. You might also want to check if the number has a `.` in it, because if so it won't be an `int`.

Comment: Hey @AkMahar Just a follow up to check this helped you at all?

Comment: yes it worked.. thanks, i forgot to mark as useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onchanged function callback like this:

```
Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              // controller: textEditingController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              onChanged: (value){
                 {
        if (value == '50') {
          print(value);
        } else {
          showInSnackBar();
        }
      },
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Number of Questions',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```